# Python: read output while executing cmd commands

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am executing cmd commands using python subprocess module. Execution of this cmd commands (eg., running some batch file, .exe file) are opening new command prompt window. How to read output of newly open cmd window using python?

I am using following code to execute commands provided by user:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, cwd = working_directory, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I am using process.communicate() method to read the output. However it is allowing me to read output of the existing command prompt window only. If user is providing command which triggers new command prompt window, then how to read output of that window?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Comment: @pankajmishra

I am using following code to execute the cmd commands provided by use. If user provides command which is opening new command window, then I am looking for solution to read output from the newly opened command window. Till now I am only able to read output from existing cmd window and not the newly opened window. Thanks for your consideration in advance. :)

`process = subprocess.Popen(command, cwd = working_directory, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: Paste this code into your question

Comment: see my answer and let me know what is not working for u

Answer (score 1):

Below code opens a new command prompt, execute a command there and display the output of that command window

```
from subprocess import Popen,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,PIPE

# /K option tells cmd to run the command and keep the command window from closing. You may use /C instead to close the command window after the 

command='cmd /C help'
proc=Popen(command,creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,stdout=PIPE)
output=proc.communicate()[0]
print ('').join(output)
```